# Time sync of the machine with specific IP

Tags: java, linux, synchronization

I would like to sync machine time with third party IP,I have IP address can you please suggest any better JAVA api to achieve this.

Apache provides NTPUDPClient but it doesn't synch i found.

Is it better to do it Java process running linux commands.My machine is linux.

Answer (score 0):

How about using NTP to synchronize the host's clock? A java implementation can be found at http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient